# Cannot find declaration file error in one file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am getting error 'Cannot find declaration file' in one file but not in other. I have the following directory structure
[image]

Error appears in `/src/contentScripts/views/App.vue` but not in `/src/components/LogoIcon.vue`
[image]

I have the following configuration

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    "types": ["unplugin-icons/types/vue"]
    }
  },

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this library with the following command `yarn add @types/icons -D`